# Unexpected tokens use ';' to separate expressions on the same line - error while creating an object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, object, abstract-factory

I am new to **kotlin**.
I was working on some design patterns used in **kotlin**. I came across **abstract factory design** and I keep getting this error while creating an object for the class. I tried the other solutions on stack overflow such as curly braces missing, but in  vain. I've attached the entire code to resolve. Can someone help me how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

**The error in console:**

`Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`

**The main.kt code:**

```
object AAbstractFactoryDesignPattern{

internal interface IAndroid{
    fun GetModelDetails(): String
}

internal interface IiOS{
    fun GetModelDetails(): String
}

internal interface IMobile{
    fun GetAndroidPhone() : IAndroid
    fun GetiOsPhone() : IiOS
}

internal class SamsungGalaxy : IAndroid{
    override fun GetModelDetails(): String {
        return "Model: Samsung Galaxy - RAM: 2GB - Camera: 13MP"
    }
}

internal class IphoneFour: IiOS{
    override fun GetModelDetails(): String {
        return "Model: Iphone 4 - RAM: 1GB - Camera: 12MP"
    }
}

internal class Samsung : IMobile{
    override fun GetAndroidPhone(): IAndroid {
        return  SamsungGalaxy()
    }

    override fun GetiOsPhone(): IiOS {
        return IphoneFour()
    }
}


internal class MobileClient(factory: IMobile){
    var androidPhone: IAndroid
    var iOSPhone: IiOS
    fun GetAndroidPhoneDetails(): String{
        return  androidPhone.GetModelDetails()
    }
    fun GetIOSPhoneDetails(): String{
        return  iOSPhone.GetModelDetails()
    }
    init {
        androidPhone = factory.GetAndroidPhone()
        iOSPhone = factory.GetiOsPhone()
    }

}


@JvmStatic
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    val samsungMobilePhone: Samsung() //error line
    val samsungClient: MobileClient(samsungMobilePhone) //error line
    println(samsungClient.GetAndroidPhoneDetails())
    println(samsungClient.GetIOSPhoneDetails())
}
```

}

Comment: That's much more code than needed to demonstrate the problem, which makes it unnecessarily hard to follow. Please consider cutting it down to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is the point of the code to be that complex for practicing I guess. Though I am not sure.  Anyway thanks for the tip @gidds

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a variable, a colon (:) is for explicitly specify the variable's type. It looks like the colons on the error line should be equals (=) instead.

Try changing your "error lines" to this:

```
val samsungMobilePhone = Samsung() //error line
val samsungClient = MobileClient(samsungMobilePhone) //error line
```

Alternatively, if you want to be explicit about the type:

```
val samsungMobilePhone: IMobile = Samsung() //error line
val samsungClient: MobileClient = MobileClient(samsungMobilePhone) //error lines
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Silly of me to have made this error and spend hours solving it. Thanks again.